# JAXB marshelling

Tags: java, xml, spring, jaxb

I am writing a JAXB class to parse below xml. I am always getting null value for trackinginfoList and response status is having value, I am not sure what is problem with this code, could you please advise?

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "CargoTrackingRespone")
   public class CargoTrackingRespone {

   private List<TrackingInfo> trackingInfoList;

   private ResponseStatus responseStatus;

   @XmlElements({@XmlElement(name = "TrackingInfo", type = TrackingInfo.class)} )
   @XmlElementWrapper(name = "TrackingInfoList" )
   public List<TrackingInfo> getTrackingInfoList() {
    return trackingInfoList;
  }

  public void setTrackingInfoList(List<TrackingInfo> trackingInfoList) {
    this.trackingInfoList = trackingInfoList;
  }

  @XmlElement(name = "Status")
  public ResponseStatus getResponseStatus() {
    return responseStatus;
  }

  public void setResponseStatus(ResponseStatus responseStatus) {
    this.responseStatus = responseStatus;
  }

}
```

The XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CargoTrackingRespone>
  <TrackingInfo>
    <TrackID>12345</TrackID>
    <TrackStatus>
      <Code>ERROR</Code>
      <Description>No tracking information found</Description>
      <StatusUpdateDateTime>2014-01-14T14:51:11.551-06:00</StatusUpdateDateTime>
    </TrackStatus>
  </TrackingInfo>
  <Status>
    <Code>ERROR</Code>
    <Description>No shipment information available</Description>
    <ReasonCode>No Shipment.</ReasonCode>
  </Status>
</CargoTrackingRespone>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can annotate the property as the following to match your XML:

```
@XmlElement(name = "TrackingInfo")
public List<TrackingInfo> getTrackingInfoList() {
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/jaxb-collection-properties.html

Answer (score 0):

I think your TrackingInfo element is wrapped with in TrackingInfoList. So your xml should look like .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CargoTrackingRespone>
  <TrackingInfoList>    
      <TrackingInfo>
        <TrackID>12345</TrackID>
        <TrackStatus>
          <Code>ERROR</Code>
          <Description>No tracking information found</Description>
          <StatusUpdateDateTime>2014-01-14T14:51:11.551-06:00</StatusUpdateDateTime>
        </TrackStatus>
      </TrackingInfo>
  <TrackingInfoList>
  <Status>
    <Code>ERROR</Code>
    <Description>No shipment information available</Description>
    <ReasonCode>No Shipment.</ReasonCode>
  </Status>
</CargoTrackingRespone>
```

I have created a class in my test and marshal the xsd and generated sample xml file and found that the difference between your xml and what I got from test has this difference.